# How to access the commandline from JScript

Tags: cmd, wsh, jscript

I am trying to write a windows JS script that iterates through a bunch of folders and deletes each one with a special program because for some reason these folders don't delete normally. My problem is that I can't figure out how to just simply run a command on the command line like you would in a batch file. Obviously, you can't just call it directly, but I've googled and googled and can't find anything.

The command string I want to run is `"C:\Program Files\Unlocker\Unlocker.exe" "E:\.Trash-1000\expunged\2443302239\recup_dir.275" -D`. If someone could write me out a simple script that can do this, that would be great. Also, if you could put it in a for loop from 100 to 999 and replace the 275 with the loop var that would be even better.

Comment: http://www.winscripter.com/WSH/System/105.aspx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code.

```
cmdPrefix='"C:\Program Files\Unlocker\Unlocker.exe" "';
dirPrefix='E:\.Trash-1000\expunged\2443302239\recup_dir.';
dirSuffix='';
cmdSuffix='" -D';
showUI=true;
shell=WScript.CreateObject('WScript.Shell');
fso=WScript.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
for (i=100; i<=999; i++) {
  folder=dirPrefix+i+dirSuffix;
  if (fso.FolderExists(folder)) {
    shell.Run(cmdPrefix+folder+cmdSuffix, showUI?1:0, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not all of the directories exist. Is there a way to skip the directory of it don't exist?